# Binomial distribution with small $p$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, reference-request

Let $X$ be a random variable follows the binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p = \frac{\log n}{n}$.

Is it true that there exists a polynomial $q$ such that $\Pr[X > q(\log n)] < \frac{1}{n}$?

UPD: I have understood: this is true for $q(\log n) = \log^2 n$.

Then the required probability is less then $$n \cdot {{n}\choose{\log^2 n}} \cdot{ \left( \frac{\log n}{n} \right)}^{\log^2 n} < n \cdot \frac{(\log n)^{\log^2 n}}{(\log^2 n)!}$$
This is of course is less than $\frac{1}{n}$.

However I still have a question: can we prove it by using some more general fact? Could you give a reference? Thank you.

Comment: in the case the polynomial is $(ln(x))^2$, I have tried to apply Markov's inequality, but it is not the good way  because it provides a too large bound. Besides, prefer now standard notation $\ln(x)$ to $\log(x).$

Comment: About the notation $\ln x$, it seems preferred in calculus and sciences, economics, finances, but $\log x$ is more preferred in analysis or number theory.